# Why can't I import modules from my PYTHONPATH in Python 3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-import, python-module

I have a package installed in `/u/home/j/joelfred/python-dev-modules`. It looks like:

```
/a
    __init__.py
    b.py
```

The source for `b.py` is simply:

```
def hello():
    print('hi yourself')
```

And for `__init__.py`:

```
import b
```

First, I make sure I'm in my home directory, and set my PYTHONPATH:

```
$ cd
$ export PYTHONPATH=/u/home/j/joelfred/python-dev-modules/
```

Then I run `python3`:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Mar 18 2015, 17:28:34) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/u/home/j/joelfred/python-dev-modules/a/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import b
ImportError: No module named 'b'
```

Okay, that's weird. But if I change `__init__.py` to be blank:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Mar 18 2015, 17:28:34) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import a.b as b
>>> b.hello()
hi yourself
>>>
```

What on earth is going on?

Comment: Doesn't work, invalid syntax:

Python 3.4.3 (default, Mar 18 2015, 17:28:34) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/u/home/j/joelfred/python-dev-modules/a/__init__.py", line 1
    import .b
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: you should `from .b import *`

Comment: Okay, that works, but why? What if I don't want `hello` in `a`'s namespace? Why doesn't the way I did it work?

Comment: If you don't want `hello` in `a`'s namespace, you should define a list with a special name `__all__` in `b` and not put `hello` in it. You might want to take a look at answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3 all imports are absolute.  You can't do `import b` unless `b` itself is a top-level module/package available on `sys.path`.  If you want to import `b` from inside `a`, use an explicit relative import:

```
from . import b
```

Comment: Thanks, that was driving me crazy. I'll accept your answer as soon as the system lets me. Is there someplace in the python documentation that points this out?

Comment: @Joel there may be a more friendly page that describes the Python 3 import differences, but [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) is where the changes originated.

Comment: @Joel: [The documentation on `import`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) gives an outline, with a link to the (lengthy) [full description](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#importsystem) of the import system.  Absolute/relative imports are described in [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).  The fact that implicit relative imports used to work in Python 2 but don't in Python 3 is mentioned in basically every list of differences between Python 2 and 3, for instance [here](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax).

Comment: @BrenBarn Thanks, I feel a bit silly for missing a basic change in the language. I wish there'd been that warning on the modules documentation page somewhere.